# Connect to a mysql database server through a shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, sh

I want to write a shell script where I want to connect to a MySQL database server by providing user id and password in the shell script only and then run my drop and create database queries. The server will be in a different box-like Rubik. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Kindly post some of your code / efforts, then only we can help you.

Comment: I am using a gcloud to connect. I am writing first time shell scripts so forgive if i sound wrong. I log in to my cluster and the run my glcoud command -> gcloud sql connect ql03-dd97-mysql --user=root --quiet . So now, I want to write the script to directly access it from my .sh file and by providing id and password and it should connect it.

Answer (score 4):

first you need a mysql client, install it if you don't have it

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```

then you must write like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER='username'
PASS='password'
PORT=3160
HOST='hostname'
DBASE='mysqlDbName'

Query='SELECT * FROM table WHERE some=other LIMIT 10'

mysql -u$USER -p$PASS -P$PORT -h$HOST -D$DBASE <<EOF 
$Query
EOF

// or you simple write the MYSQL code like
mysql -u$USER -p$PASS -P$PORT -h$HOST -D$DBASE <<EOF
USE mysql
SHOW tables
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some=other LIMIT 10
DROP table
EOF

// or in shell script and save your result to a file
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u$USER -p$PASS -h$HOST -A \
 --default-character-set=utf8 \
 -e $Query > /home/user/result.txt
```